# An example for a topological space $X$ in which $C_p(X)$ is countably tight but not sequential

Tags: general-topology

Is there an example for a topological space $X$ in which $C_p(X)$ is countably tight but not sequential?

$C_p(X)$ is the space of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ with the topology generated from open sets $[F,(a,b)] = \{ f:X \rightarrow \mathbb R | f(F) \subset (a,b) \}$ where $F \subset X$ is finite and $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$ is an open segment.

A topological space is sequential if a set $A$ in $X$ is closed if and only if $A$ contains all limit points of sequences $\{ x_n \}_{n \in \omega} \subset A$.

A topological space is countably tight if whenever $x \in \overline A \setminus A$, there exists a countable set $K \subset A$ such that $x \in \overline K$

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope that somebody will provide a more direct answer. But one example can be found from these references:

- Whenever $X$ is compact, then $C_p(X)$ is countably tight. See [this post](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/cpx-is-countably-tight-when-x-is-compact/) on Dan Ma's Topology Blog, Theorem I.4.1 in Arkhangel'skii A.V. Topological function spaces  or [Problem 149](http://books.google.com/books?id=EcINw8FHIAoC&pg=PA18) in Tkachuk: A $C_p$-Theory Problem Book.
- The space $C_p([0,1])$ is not sequential. (It is not even embeddable into a sequential space.) See  Viacheslav I. Malykhin: $C_p(I)$ is not subsequential, Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae (1999), Volume: 40, Issue: 4, page 785-788. [eudml](https://eudml.org/doc/248416), [dml.cz](http://dml.cz/handle/10338.dmlcz/119131)

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the references!